# How to change Apple Developer Enterprise Program to Organization Program?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, iphone-developer-program

Instead of getting an Apple Developer Organization Program, my collegue got Apple Developer Enterprise Program. I found this by seeing the Account type as it says "In-House" instead of "Organization". Can I convert it by any means? I want to distribute apps in Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

A corporation can enroll in both Apple's Enterprise program and Apple's Standard Company Developer program.  Many companies have both so they can distribute both to their employees and to the App store.

So you don't need to change your program.  Just apply for the other.

Comment: I don't need one. Because it's not a big enterprise and we don't have any idea of hosting apps in-house.